# Bulbs in a circuit fuse type

Tags: voltage

My question is about a rotel rt 226 1978 radio, it takes three[image] 6.3v 250ma to light the display. What would happen if I put 6.3 300ma fuse bulbs in instead? Will it work just not glow as bright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're wired in parallel, directly to one of the outputs of the transformer, so as long as the voltage rating of the bulbs is correct, it will probably be fine. However, depending on how much margin there is in the design of the transformer, the 20% extra current could be on the verge of overloading it.

Comment: Hmm. There may be a discrepancy. A manual I found online at hifiengine.com shows the bulbs as being driven by a winding on the transformer that's only rated at 6.3V @ 250 mA. Something is fishy here!

Comment: The 300 mA bulb should be slightly brighter than the 250 mA bulb, as it is higher power (power (watts) is volts times amps).  for comparison, consider the brightness  of 100 Watt  and 60 Watt houshold bulbs.

Comment: @ Peter Bennett thanks I just needed it explained like that, that shouldn’t damage a circuit though going just a bit higher?